# ROS Master-Client Communication

Tags: ros, master, winros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just installed winros (Msvc build environment) on my Windows 7 (x64) machine and I am trying to send a message from my ROS master on my Ubuntu machine to winros (client). I can ping both ways.
However, when I try to set master IP and ROS IP on Windows using:

export ROS_MASTER_URI="hxxp://XXX.XXX.X.XXX:11311/ 
export ROS_IP=XXX.XXX.X.XX

It gives me an error saying "export is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".
Any ideas on what the source of this error could be?

It gave me a similar error when I tried to use 'wget' command. I resolved that by adding Wget .exe file location to the PATH.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51009/ros-master-client-communication/) by [Merdad](https://answers.ros.org/users/3506/merdad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2012-12-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Merdad](https://answers.ros.org/users/3506/merdad/) on 2012-12-23**:
Thanks for the answer.  I used SET instead of EXPORT and it worked. However, they use EXPORT in their win_ros troubleshooting guide! This is the link: http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/Resolving%20One%20Way%20Broadcasting%20Issues

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-24**:
likely due to mingw use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because `export` is a Linux command, Windows don't know what expot means.

Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559816/how-to-export-and-import-environment-variables-in-windowse-g-xp).

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2